# Map the - key to "delete the current line, then paste it below the one we're on now"

Tags: vimscript

I am doing the exercise of [learn vim the hard way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/03.html)

I have trouble mapping "the - key to "delete the current line, then paste it below the one we're on now".

I tried:

- `:map - dd p`
- `:map - :dd p`
- `:map - :dd <enter> p <enter>`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before creating a mapping you should try the actual command by yourself: Here you want to delete a line with `dd` and then paste it with `p`. When you do that in normal mode you simply press the keys <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> without anything else in between, so that is what you need to do too in your mapping.

This means that you mapping should be `map - ddp`. You don't need to use the command mode (with `:` and `<enter>`) since `dd` and `p` are normal mode commands, i.e. the key you press directly in normal mode.

Also two other things:

- If you continue reading *learn vimscript the hard way* (or maybe you miss this part) you'll see that it's important to use non recursive version of the map command so your actual mapping should be `nnoremap - ddp`
- And `<enter>` is not a valid key representation in vimscript, you want to use `<CR>` instead.

Comment: Oh, I see, that makes sence. Thank you